# View container of a control in a Form

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm wont to work with netbeans, and with Visual studio I can't find the way to view a hierarchical relation of the control(Parent container ---> Child) in the form, something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to have a view like this in Visual Studio 2010 with c# programming language ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Use View + Other Windows + Document Outline.